# creating a const value based on user input

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a user input and set it as the PUZZLESIZE which is used by int peg and row but am getting the expression must have a constant value.

How would I go about getting a user input and setting it as a global const that struct Board will recognize?

```
int a;
const int PIECE = a;
const int PUZZLESIZE = ((PUZZLESIZE *(PUZZLESIZE+1)) /2);

typedef struct Board {


    int *row[PUZZLESIZE];
    int peg[PIECE];

    int lastmove;
    struct Board *prevBoard;

    int prow;
    int pcol;

} Board;



int main()

{
  scanf("%d",a);

}
```

Thanks for any help in advanced

Comment: You can't turn a runtime value into a compile-time constant.

Comment: Also note that a `const` value is not the same as a constant expression. You need the latter for `PUZZLESIZE`, and you can't get it at runtime. But you can initialize a `const int` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Re-setting the value of a `const` variable at runtime is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You just defined `PIECE` as a `const` (constant variable):

```
const int PIECE = a;
```

So, you cannot change the value of `PIECE` after starting the program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rethink a little about how your program will work. In addition since you are using C++ you may consider the use of the language features and libraries so that you can follow best practices as recommended by @Joren.

You have 2 options:

Option 1 : Make PuzzleSize your largest supported puzzle.

If you do this all you need to do is validate the user input against this size. 
In addition you don't have to fiddle with memory allocation.

- Simple solution
- Potentially can have large segments of unused memory

Option 2: Make row a double pointer and use new to allocate your rows.

```
typedef struct Board 
{
    int **row; // int *row[PUZZLESIZE];
    ....
}
```

once the user sets the input you can validate the input and do this

```
int main() 
{
    scanf("%d",a);
    row = new int*[a];    }
```

Don't forget to take a look at your C++ book and read up on const, multidimensional arrays ,and new.

Good Luck!

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of `malloc` in a  C++ program. Or `scanf`, or raw pointers, or `typedef struct`.

Comment: @Joren, thanks for the comment. I modified from malloc to new as you are right its not good practice and it's directly related to the question. In addition I have added a "disclaimer". I was not trying to advocate or recommend, just trying to show muffindho with the code he provided. I think smart pointers, the stl libraries, usage of typedef, and input streams are outside of the scope of the question as each one is a separate topic.